# ToolTipService using cached values despite calling provider

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime

I have a UWP app with a UI element for which I've called `ToolTipService.SetToolTip` and passed in an object which invokes a callback to determine the result of `.ToString()` as the value:

```
        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(Status, new DynamicString(() =>
        {
            var remaining = time - DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
            var tooltipText = remaining.Humanize(precision: 5, minUnit: remaining.Hours > 1 ? TimeUnit.Minute : TimeUnit.Second);
            return tooltipText;
        }));
```

Each time I hover over the element in question, this callback is invoked and a new tooltip text value is computed and returned. Despite this, the UI always shows the old value:

[image]

[image]

I can understand if the result is always cached, but if that's the case, why is my `.ToString()` method on the passed object being called each time in the first place? Since the result is being calculated anyway, it should obviously also be used.

I imagine in the callback I can remove the tooltip and then re-create it with the new value, but that seems a rather circuitous approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While, for my own sanity, I would still prefer a solution that prevented the caching of the `.ToString()` call of the passed object to `ToolTipService.SetToolTip(xxx, value)`, this is what I'm using for now:

```
var tooltip = new ToolTip();
var tooltipText = new TextBlock();
tooltip.Content = tooltipText;
tooltip.Opened += (s, e) =>
{
    var remaining = time - DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    tooltipText.Text = remaining.Humanize(precision: 5, minUnit: remaining.Hours >= 1 ? TimeUnit.Minute : TimeUnit.Second);
};

ToolTipService.SetToolTip(Status, tooltip);
```